# Ansible Tower - Using an isolation node to gather data via the delegate to

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

So i'm running a playbook that outputs fact data to a folder, and that works fine outside of AWX as I only have one executaion node...

I'm trying to run a playbook and I have the execution node working fine (in that, it runs the code). But the delegate_to (which is writing out the facts), is running on the AWX task container, whereas I want it to run on the execution node!

I'm using delegate_to: localhost, which i guess is the problem, but I can't find anywhere in the docs what I can use to say delegate to execution node (i expected localhost was the execution node as it was running the playbook!)

Any help appreciated!

```
---
# tasks file for store_fact
- name: Collect Facts
  setup:
    filter:
      - 'ansible_distribution'
      - 'ansible_uptime_seconds'
      - 'ansible_kernel'
      - 'ansible_memfree_mb'
      - 'ansible_memtotal_mb'
      - 'ansible_processor_vcpus'
      - 'ansible_distribution_version'
      - 'ansible_fqdn'
      - 'ansible_local'

  register: ansible_facts

- name: Create LogData
  file:
    path: "{{ fact_folder }}"
    state: directory
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
    
- name: Copy Ansible facts to a file
  copy:
    content: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
    dest: "{{ fact_folder }}/{{ ansible_fqdn}}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: What are you targeting, in the `hosts` of the parent playbook? Most likely what you want to just to remove the `delegate_to`.

Comment: if i remove the delegate_to then it will collect the facts on the individual nodes, and i need them all collected on the execution node!